# How to put values into checkedlistbox in c#?

Tags: c#, process, checkedlistbox

c# learner here.

I have found this code. It shows running processes in console. 
I want to show processes in checkedlistbox.

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process theprocess in processlist){
Console.WriteLine(“Process: {0} ID: {1}”, theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
}
```

Comment: Is there a checkedlistbox for console application?

Comment: `cb.Items.Add` - just for GUI

Comment: You create a new project as winforms or wpf project, add a checkedlistbox to the form and in winforms replace the Console.WriteLine with something like this in the form load: `checkedListBox1.Item.Add( theprocess.ProcessName + "ID:" +  theprocess.Id);`